# getting exception while parsing xml with out root element

Tags: spring-batch

I am parsing(reading) an xml file(without root tag) that has multiple records through spring batch, but it is throwing an error. It works fine with the root tag but i want to parse it without root tag.

Below is the exception:

caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[640,2]
Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:276)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.stax.DefaultFragmentEventReader.nextEvent(DefaultFragmentEventReader.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.stax.DefaultFragmentEventReader.markFragmentProcessed(DefaultFragmentEventReader.java:184)
    ... 33 more

and my fragmentRootElementName RTT

```
   <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="RTT" />
```

below is the xml syntax:

```
    <RTT>
    <tranaction> </transaction>
    <data></date>
    </RTT>
    <RTT>
    <tranaction> </transaction>
    <data></date>
    </RTT>
    <RTT>
    <tranaction> </transaction>
    <data></date>
    </RTT>
```

It works fine if i put it in a root element :

```
    <RttData> <RTT></RTT><RTT></RTT> <RTT></RTT> <RTT></RTT></RttDate>
```

Comment: XML without a root element isn't valid XML.  There are ways to hack around this, but your best bet would be to fix your XML.

Comment: XML generated from a legacy system. And it can not be changed.

Comment: Well, it can...it's a file on the file system, right?  You can generate a new file that wraps that in a valid root element or you can create a `Resource` implementation that returns an `InputStream` that prepends the valid root element.  You could also look into another parser, but I'm not sure that any will accept truly invalid XML like that...